# Video Card Issue?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, hdmi, intel-graphics, throttling

I have a laptop with Windows 10 Pro, Core i3-3217U, Intel HD4000 iGPU and 8GB 1600MHz DDR3 RAM. Whenever I play any game using it's built-in display (1366x768 display), My laptop gets throttled in just 5 minutes. But when I play the game on my 3D tv using HDMI then my laptop never throttles. In fact I get 30-35 fps via HDMI.

Even after Throttling, frequency remains at peak point. that is 1800MHz. RAM usage is not affected at all. Disk IO is perfect.

All the problem is laptop becomes dead slow.

Games that I play are -- BeamNG Drive, Spintires, Prototype 2, Castlevania Lord of Shadows 2, GTA 5 and Devil May Cry Reboot.

What is the problem?

I play games at medium to full settings depending upon game requirements. I tried ThrottleStop. but that does not seems to work. I tried XTU and all the temperatures are normal.

I have locked BIOS.

Comment: What is the exact make and model of your laptop?

Comment: Acer Aspire E1-570

Answer (score -1):

When you plug your 3D tv display (no throttling), your built in display is turned off ?

I think about a built-in power supply problem. Builtin display is powered up by built in power supply, but 3D TV has its own power supply... Something like If you ask your laptop more performance, it could not give it to you because of a power problem...?

Comment: Yes my built-in display is turned off. I dont know much about Power things but i always plugin my laptop to my Power Adapter. Some the things i noticed are. My laptop never throttles on Battery but throttles on AC Power Supply. thats weird